# What to do when the image doesn't appear to be hyperlinked, but devtools is showing the url is there, yet you can't click it?

Tags: blogger

I successfully added a banner to my blogger account on the right side. Only problem is that the banner doesn't seem to be hyperlinked.  Yet, when I check the resulting blog using DevTools, the URL isn't actually missing from the code.  So I have tried changing the link, and it hasn't helped. I have tried messing around with the code, but it breaks when I do.

````
  <a href='http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1' target='_blank'/><img alt='' height='725' src='http://www.ramycapital.ca/images/banner1news.png' width='160'/> 
    
      
    
        </div>```
````

Comment: ''''<div id='RightFloatAds' style='right: 0px; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 65px; background-color:black;color:black;border:5px solid black;'>
  <a href='http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1' target='_blank'/><img alt='' height='725' src='http://www.ramycapital.ca/images/banner1news.png' width='160'/> </div>''''   Full code

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor tag is closing itself instead of wrapping the image (because of the slash at the end):

`<a href='http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1' target='_blank'/>`

What you want is this:

`<a href='http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1' target='_blank'><img .../></a>`

Comment: like this "<a href='http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1' target='_blank'><img alt='' height='725' src='ramycapital.ca/images/banner1news.png' width='160'/></a> </div>"  ?

Comment: I attempted your suggestion and it not only did not link the url but also broke the image grab

Comment: i fixed the broken image thing, but this still did not work to solve the hyperlink not showing up.

Comment: I think I actually misunderstood you the first time, but when I try your solution again i get  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2955; columnNumber: 324; The element type "a" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</a>".

Comment: lol sorry for all the replies but im burnt out today obviously. I entered the ended </a> as you suggest and nothing was broken but it still didn't work to pull the link.